# File handling compilation error

Tags: c++

I have a problem with file handling.  I'm writing code for file handling, that looks like this:

```
ofstream SaveFile("/home/core-site2.xml") 

//SaveFile<<"<?xml version="1.0"?>" ;
SaveFile <<endl ;
SaveFile<<"<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>" ;
```

When I compile this file I get the following error:

> error: expected ‘;’ before ‘text’

What shouuld I do to remove the error?
How do I write these line properly?

Comment: check if you have missed out to put a semicolon (;) in the previous line or not. and comment back. can you please format the question bit more properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of SaveFile misses a trailing ';'. Also, you need to escape the quotes inside the string:

```
SaveFile<<"<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"configuration.xsl\"?>" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ofstream SaveFile("/home/core-site2.xml");
```

and

```
SaveFile<<"<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"configuration.xsl\"?>" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ofstream SaveFile("/home/core-site2.xml")
```

This line lacks a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi-colon from the end of your ofstream declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`SaveFile<<"<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"configuration.xsl\"?>" ;`

You need to escape the quotes in the string. Otherwise the compiler thinks they are the end of the string.